# Conditionally replace a value in a data frame with a value from a second data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a data frame, `d1`, that looks like this:

```
  site code trait
1    1    A   1.0
2    2    B   1.3
3    3    A    NA
4    4    B   2.9
5    5    A    NA
```

Here is the dput to generate `d1`:

```
structure(list(site = 1:5, code = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), trait = c(1, 1.3, 
NA, 2.9, NA)), .Names = c("site", "code", "trait"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have a second data frame, `d2`, that looks like this:

```
  code trait
1    A   1.5
2    B   2.5
```

Here is the dput to generate `d2`:

```
structure(list(code = structure(1:2, .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
    trait = c(1.5, 2.5)), .Names = c("code", "trait"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like a piece of code that replaces the NA values of `trait` with the trait value from `d2` that matches the `code` character for a particular row in `d1`. The final output of `d1` would look like this:

```
  site code trait
1    1    A   1.0
2    2    B   1.3
3    3    A   1.5
4    4    B   2.9
5    5    A   1.5
```

Things I've tried:

```
d1$trait<- ifelse(is.na(d1$trait),d2$trait[d2$code == d1$code],d1$trait)
```

When using this code I'm getting a warning:

> Warning messages: 1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) : longer object length
>   is not a multiple of shorter object length 2: In ==.default(d2$code,
>   d1$code) : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object
>   length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ifelse` syntax is close, but the problematic bit is:

```
d2$trait[d2$code == d1$code]
```

Here, you are trying to look up the `d2$trait` value corresponding to the correct `code` value from `d1`, but you are actually just comparing the corresponding elements of `d2$code` to `d1$code`. The operation can instead be accomplished with `match`:

```
d1$trait<- ifelse(is.na(d1$trait),d2$trait[match(d1$code, d2$code)], d1$trait)
d1
#   site code trait
# 1    1    A   1.0
# 2    2    B   1.3
# 3    3    A   1.5
# 4    4    B   2.9
# 5    5    A   1.5
```

An alternative would be to just replace the missing values, again using `match` to grab the relevant elements from `d2$trait`:

```
d1$trait[is.na(d1$trait)] <- d2$trait[match(d1$code[is.na(d1$trait)], d2$code)]
d1
#   site code trait
# 1    1    A   1.0
# 2    2    B   1.3
# 3    3    A   1.5
# 4    4    B   2.9
# 5    5    A   1.5
```

While `match` and `merge` are internally doing very similar things, I find the `match` syntax to be a bit easier to use because you don't need to create an intermediate object via `merge` and then grab the relevant information from that intermediate object.

Comment: I agree, match is definitely preferable to merge. Thanks for this suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple task for merge:

```
df12 <- merge(df1, df2, by="code", all.x=TRUE)
df12$trait <- ifelse(is.na(df12$trait.x), df12$trait.y, df12$trait.x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also accomplish this without a intermediate object using a `dplyr` like pipe:

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(df1, df2, by="code") %>%
  mutate(trait=ifelse(is.na(trait.x), trait.y, trait.x)) %>%
  select(site, code, trait)
```

The advantage here is that you don't need an intermediate object period and you are ready to start working with the data in the pipe.

Comment: thanks @boshek I see what you mean as it is one command, however the chosen answer is also one line of code with no intermediate object, and doesn't require anything beyond base (no package load required).